# centering links in a drop down javascript menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down menu that has sub menus, the entire menu spans the whole width of the browser, right now the links are all positioned to the left of the screen. What I would like is my links to be all in the center of the screen, with the orange background still spanning the entire width of the browser.

Here is the code:

inside the head goes the javascript and the css, and the rest in the body:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#menu li").hover(function(){
        $(this).children(":hidden").slideDown();

    },function(){
        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideUp();

    });

});

</script>


<style>

#menu{
height: 30px;
background-color:#F90;
}

#menu li li:hover{
background-color:yellow;
cursor:pointer;
}

#menu ul, #menu li{
list-style-type:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#menu li{
float:left;
width:120px;
list-style-type:none;
line-height:30px;
text-align:center;
}

#menu li ul{
position:absolute;
background-color:#f90;
display:none;
}

#menu li li{
float:none;
padding:2px;
}

#menu a{
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}
</style>



<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Info</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.example.com">example</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin: auto` and `display: table`:

**css**

```
#menu{
    height: 30px;
    background-color:#F90;
    width:100%;
}

#menu li li:hover{
    background-color:yellow;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#menu ul, #menu li{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:auto;/*Add this*/
    display: table;/*Add this*/
}

#menu li{
    float:left;
    width:120px;
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu li ul{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#f90;
    display:none;
}

#menu li li{
    float:none;
    padding:2px;
}

#menu a{
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j72p9/16/)

Comment: what you wrote works, but now the orange background doesn't span the entire browser width, what could we do to fix that.